# Xperia S, sleep-to-snap not capturing automatically

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, camera, sony-xperia-s

Xperia S has the [sleep-to-snap function](http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/products/phones/xperia-s/):

> A single key press takes you from sleep to snap in just over a second.

But when I press the shutter-button, the phone wakes, goes into camera mode, but it doesn't snap a photo - I have to press the snap button for that.

How do I make it also snap automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend showed me how to, you go to the Camera App's Settings, then go to "Quick launch", and check "Launch and Capture". It was set on "Launch only (still camera)".